# Yii2 Models for Modules

Tags: module, yii2, models

In my application I have all models in `app/models`. Now I created module in `app/modules/admin`. Should I use models form `app/models` or create new models in `app/modules/admin/models`?

What is the best practice?

Comment: refer the Yii Official Tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html

Comment: so should I create new models in module? How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create models specific for admin module in `app/modules/admin/models` and create models common for whole application in `app/models`.

You can extend existing models in new module if you need to have specific behavior.

In `app/models`:

```
namespace app\models;

class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
}
```

In `app/modules/admin/models`:

```
namespace app\modules\admin\models;

class Post extends \app\models\Post
{
}
```

So you can share business logic between modules.

Also take a look at [Yii 2 Advanced Project Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md). There are three `models` directories:

```
backend/models
frontend/models
common/models
```